# Android Studio get char code

Tags: android, char, zxing

In ZXing return I have code:

```
result.getContents().substring(0, 1)
```

And I would like get first char and return his char-code. The geting first char work correctly, but I don't found code to change char to char code.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int charCode = (int) result.getContents().substring(0, 1).charAt(0);
```

Note: `substring(0,1)` might be unnecessary here.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get a char at certain position, use the charAt function that is available in the String class. See below.

```
char a_char =  result.getContents().charAt(0);
```

Comment: Not `.substring(0, 1).charAt(0)`?

Comment: @Peter substring is useless as it gets in this case

Comment: can you add some explanation?